# Reload a div on the click of a button in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to refresh a `div` in a `Lightning Component`, the same as how we use `rerender` in a `Visualforce Page`. How can I do so?

Comment: i agree with Aakanksha here, since this has been put on hold to be having specific problem, i come across the problem where i have one text field and one date field for form and have one button that create one record from this data.  in button controller logic i have validation that checks it text cannot be null and date cannot be past( this validation done) , once i got the error in the form , i filled the details correctly and clicked the button , record is getting created but errors still display on the screen. how to remove the errors automatically, when correct data enters.

Answer (score 2):

The view is bound to the model and data. In other words, simply setting the component's data should automatically "re-render" the associated elements. In some cases, you may need to use [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm), which will cause all of the data in the app to reload. If you're not experiencing the appropriate refreshes, there's something else wrong with your code (most likely, not setting the right data).